# vba excel Range + Like

Tags: like, range

Возможно как то реализовать в vba такой код
заменить

```
.Width = Range("Width_block_TopMain").Value
```

на

```
 .Width = Range("*" Like "*").Value
```

Спасибо

Comment: Не совсем понятен твой вопрос. Что ты пытаешься сделать?

Comment: Поддерживаю, нужно понимание что собираетесь получить в качестве результата?!